# how to populate visualforce page field after clicking on a link

Tags: visualforce

I have this VF page..
[image]

when i click on "New Incident" it redirect me to another vf page.i.e.
[image]

Here I need to autopopulate `client id` field with current user, and business unit as 'PHS'.

Comment: Does that other Visfualforce page have an Apex controller? If so you can initialize the values in the controller's constructor.

Comment: it has extension controller.Can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the information you need about the record from the [StandardController](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_methods.htm):

```
public with sharing class MyController {

    public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        // This Id is null for the "New" case and non-null for the "Edit" case
        if (sc.getId() == null) {
            Incident__c incident = (Incident__c) sc.getRecord();
            incident.ClientId__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
            incident.BusinessUnit__c = 'PHS';
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Note that if you need to, you can also pass values to this page via URL parameters added in your first page and pick them up like this:

```
incident.OtherValue__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('other');
```